# Load xls files with pandas is failed

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd, apache-tika

I am trying to load an xls file with pandas using:

```
pd.read_excel(fi_name, sheet_name=None, engine=None)
```

But i get this error:

```
"XLRDError: Workbook is encrypted"
```

But file is not encrypted, i can open it with excel, and read file's text with tika package.

Is someone know how can i solve it ?

Besides, is anyone know a python package for reading all excel files format,
Even if pandas is failed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess ,I found something for your problem:

```py
import msoffcrypto

file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile (open ('encrypted.xls', 'rb')) # read the original file
file.load_key (password = 'VelvetSweatshop') # Fill in the password, if it can be opened directly, the default password is 'VelvetSweatshop'
file.decrypt (open ('decrypted.xls', 'wb')) # Save it as a new file after decryption
```

After that, you can use xlrd to open and operate the decrypted file normally.

and you can install the package with

```sh
pip install msoffcrypto
```

and you can see the full documentation [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/67593398206/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons for this:

1. The file that you are getting is not in the same file format as the file extension says.
2. Either the whole workbook or a sheet of it is password protected and hence the data being read from it is encrypted to protect the data.

Comment: 1. I load the pandas with file's bytes, not a file path.
2. File is not encrypted, i can open the excel without any problem.

Comment: Well in that case it is possible that you are able to open the file in Excel but there is a default password 'VelvetSweatshop' which you don't need to provide while opening the file in Excel but is required when reading the file in a dataframe. If this is the case you can use the 2nd solution provided. If this too doesn't solve your problem kindly provide your file and code here. Will surely try to help you!